# How can I temporarily disable ASLR (Address space layout randomization)?

Tags: kernel

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32-bits, for some experiment I need to disable ASLR; how do I accomplish that? What should I do after that to enable ASLR again?

Comment: For self only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238457/disable-and-re-enable-address-space-layout-randomization-only-for-mysef || http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15881/disable-address-space-layout-randomization-aslr-for-my-processes

Answer (score 128, accepted):

According to an article [How Effective is ASLR on Linux Systems?](https://web.archive.org/web/20210814111134/https://securityetalii.es/2013/02/03/how-effective-is-aslr-on-linux-systems/), you can configure ASLR in Linux using the `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` interface.

> The following values are supported:
>
> - 0 – No randomization. Everything is static.
> - 1 – Conservative
>   randomization. Shared libraries, stack, `mmap()`, VDSO and heap are
>   randomized.
> - 2 – Full randomization. In addition to elements listed in
>   the previous point, memory managed through `brk()` is also randomized.

So, to disable it, run

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

and to enable it again, run

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

This won't survive a reboot, so you'll have to configure this in `sysctl`. Add a file `/etc/sysctl.d/01-disable-aslr.conf` containing:

```
kernel.randomize_va_space = 0
```

should permanently disable this.

Comment: What exactly is "Full randomization"? Does that include the executable itself? And what is `brk()`?

Comment: @Shuzheng `brk()` is the break address during memory allocation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988487/what-does-the-brk-system-call-do

Comment: @Niklas - Does any of the above levels include the executable core itself?

Comment: @Shuzheng I think so, meaning that I needed to turn it off in order to succeed in provoking a buffer overflow. If ASLR is enabled then an attacker cannot easily calculate memory addresses of the running process even if he can inject and hijack the program flow. At level 1, if I understand it correctly, both the absolute and relative addresses of the process will be randomized and at level 2 also dynamic memory addresses will be randomized. There are example programs you can experiment with in a VM or container where you disable the ASLR and try to hijack the process (search for overflow)

Comment: @Shuzheng If you mean that ASLR can be disabled and enabled for the Linux Kernel itself, then that is more than I know... but surely it will be in the manual somewhere about this

Comment: @Niklas, it is still not clear whether the base address of the code segment will be loaded at a random address, only that libraries etc. are loaded at random addresses.

Comment: @Shuzheng: only PIE executables can have their text/data/bss randomized.  (That's why Ubuntu and other modern distros configure GCC to build PIEs by default, and build binary packages that way).  Traditional ELF *executables* contain absolute addresses, and don't have metadata to relocate them with runtime fixups even if anyone wanted to attempt to make the kernel do that.  [why non-pic code can't be totally ASLR using run-time fixups?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64251362).

Comment: **A PIE executable counts as a shared library, and should have its text/data/BSS ASLRed at `randomize_va_space = 1`.** (It literally is an ELF shared object with an entry point; that was historically a silly computer trick that happened to work; now it's the standard way to build executables.)

Answer (score 46):

The `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` interface controls ASLR system-wide.

If you don't want a system-wide change, use `ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE` [personality](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html) flag to temporarily disable ASLR. Controlling of this flag can be done with [`setarch`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setarch.8.html) and its `-R` option, like

```
setarch `uname -m` -R /bin/bash
```

This will open a new Bash shell for you with ASLR disabled, including all child processes run from this shell. Just `exit` the shell once you're done.

---

By the way, on i386, `ulimit -s unlimited` can effectively "disable" ASLR.

EDIT (Apr 2016): The `ulimit -s unlimited` was fixed and assigned [CVE-2016-3672](http://hmarco.org/bugs/CVE-2016-3672-Unlimiting-the-stack-not-longer-disables-ASLR.html).

Comment: Minor detail in the spirit of util-linux: instead of `uname -m` one could also use `arch`, a binary that essentially does the same.

Comment: @drumfire `arch` is not available as a busybox applet

Comment: +1 for coming back two years later and adding the information regarding CVE.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to construct a program which disables ASLR for itself when it runs, you can use the `personality` system call on Linux. Here's a recipe:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/personality.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const int old_personality = personality(ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE);
    if (!(old_personality & ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE)) {
        const int new_personality = personality(ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE);
        if (new_personality & ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE) {
            execv(argv[0], argv);
        }
    }
    printf("&argc == %p\n", (void *) &argc);
}
```

If you look at the source for `setarch`, it calls `personality` twice in roughly this pattern. The major difference is that `setarch` calls `exec` on some other program, whereas my recipe `exec`s itself. It's important that you use non-zero-ness of `& ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE` and not equality tests: else you can go into an infinite `exec` loop if you e.g. compile with `-z execstack`.

See also the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html) for `personality`.

Answer (score 4):

The more permanent ways of disabling ASLR should be kept in a VM for obvious reasons.

to test the ability to overwrite stack frame return addresses etcetera, you'll need to compile without stack canaries `-fno-stack-protector`, while to allow you to execute code on the stack you need to compile with `-z execstack`, making

```
$ gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o <my_program> my_code.c
```

Comment: It isn't so easy to disable aslr in the vm when it is enabled on the host. I find it better to always temporary disable aslr

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following command to temporarily disable ASLR.

```
sudo sysctl kernel.randomize_va_space=0
```